# How can I make a number appear in a JTextField when I click an option in a JList

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jlist

I'm currently designing some software using eclipse Java window builder and I have multiple `Jlist`s (4 to be precise).

How can I get a number to appear in a `Jtext` box when I select an Item from a number of different lists?

Comment: Add a `ListSelectionListener` to each of the `JLists`. Then when the selection is changed the event will be generated and you can get the information from each of the 4 JLists and update the text field. See [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for example code to get your started.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a selection listener:

```
JList jlist = .....
```

define the listener

```
ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener = new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent listSelectionEvent) {
        int mySelectedIndex = jlist.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println(mySelectedIndex);
        //here set the text somewher else....     
    }
};
```

set the listener to each jlist

```
jlist.addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);
```